# Übersetzung von »least of all«

Tags: translation, english-to-german, idiom

> He hardly ever scolded someone – least of all Jane.

Wie übersetzt man das ins Deutsche? Ich habe [die Übersetzungen](http://www.dict.cc/?s=least+of+all) von *least of all* nachgeschlagen, und die Vorschläge *am wenigsten* und *am allerwenigsten* scheinen hier schlecht zu passen. Die [Bedeutung](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/least+of+all) von *least of all Jane* hier ist eigentlich:

> besonders nicht Jane

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Am (aller)wenigsten" oder "erst recht nicht" gehen.

Answer (score 9):

Eine weitere Alternative ist *schon gar nicht,* z.B:

> Er schimpfte sehr selten – schon gar nicht mit Jane.